# Centos 6.3 Bind hangs on "Generating /etc/rndc.key"

Tags: centos, bind, centos6

I'm installing bind on a clean Centos 6.3 system.
In previous versions that would work like a charm, but now I get

> Generating /etc/rndc.key

when trying to start bind after the installation. 
Why is this and does anyone know how to solve this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 9):

Try using

> rndc-confgen -a -r /dev/urandom

If you're using bind-chroot, add :

> rndc-confgen -a -r /dev/urandom -t /var/named/chroot

The result should be:

> wrote key file "/etc/rndc.key"
>
> wrote key file "/var/named/chroot/etc/rndc.key"

I've found the answer [here](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-server-73/rndc-confgen-a-on-rhel6-hangs-4175419685/) and tested myself because I was having the same problem.

Cheers

Comment: I don't normally downvote, but this isn't a great idea.  The unblocking random device (`/dev/urandom) isn't random at all, merely the output of a PRNG.  That's good enough for a lot of things, but **not** for a crypto key that will probably be used unchanged for years to come.  If it's entropy shortage that's causing solsol's problem, he'd be much better off generating a strong key on a different box with lots of entropy and securely copying it to his server.

Comment: Just went through this same issue and while using urandom will work it's not really the best answer.  In my case I was SSH'd to a VM so my keyboard randomness wasn't making it to the program.  Generated the key by opening up the VMware console for the machine and starting the service there.

Answer (score 4):

I'm sorry if this seems trite, but I suspect the error message means that the system is trying to generate an rndc key in `/etc/rndc.key`.  Such a key is needed for correct operation of BIND as it's configured out-the-box in CentOS, though it would only need to be created that first time.

I suspect it's hanging on the creation because you're ssh'ed onto a remote server, one without a handy human being attached via keyboard and mouse, who can provide the entropy that such a key generation requires.

You can test the first part of this hypothesis by doing

```
ls -al /etc/rndc.key
```

If it's not there, that's the problem.

You can test the second part by doing

```
sudo rndc-confgen -a -c /etc/rndc.key
```

on your remote server.  If it hangs, try doing

```
rndc-confgen -a -c /tmp/disposable.key
```

on your remote server.  If it, too, hangs, the problem is not with the file `/etc/rndc.key`, but with the act of key generation, as I suspect.  Try

```
rndc-confgen -a -c /tmp/disposable.key
```

on your local desktop (assuming that you have the `bind` package installed, or whatever is suitable for your local distro).  If that completes, the problem is very likely the availability of entropy (desktops have a lot of it, colocated servers less so; as I said, having a human being on the end of a HID cable makes lots of useful randomness available to the system).

You can either arrange for the remote system to have some entropy (which is somewhat beyond the scope of this answer), or generate the keyfile locally and copy it up to the server (it's only a correctly-formatted, pre-shared nonce secret).

If you do the latter, make sure the file is owned by `root:named` and mode `440` on the remote system.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem, but fixed it. All I've done: just typed a few letters after it got stuck at generating and it started with no problems.

Comment: That's often sufficient to generate enough entropy for the system to finish generating a key.

Answer (score 2):

RHEL 6 (on which CentOS is based) apparently no longer generates the rndc.key during installation - for details please refer to this bug report: [Centos 6.3 Bind hangs on "Generating /etc/rndc.key"](https://serverfault.com/questions/440861/centos-6-3-bind-hangs-on-generating-etc-rndc-key)

As a result, the key is automatically generated on the first start of named service.
The command line may seem confusing as it ends with column, like this:

```
[root@linx etc]# service named start 
Generating /etc/rndc.key:
```

as if it prompts for input but it is not. It may take some time, maybe 30 - 60 seconds so just wait, it should finish like this:

```
[root@linx etc]# service named start
Generating /etc/rndc.key:                                  [  OK  ]
Starting named:                                            [  OK  ]
```

Hope it helps.